# General formula for integral of polynomial expressed as roots product

Tags: calculus, integration, polynomials, indefinite-integrals

I’m wondering whether there is a general formula to integrate a polynomial expressed as product of its $n$ roots, in other words

$\int p(x)dx$

With
$p(x) = (x-r_1) (x-r_2)...(x-r_n)$

So to have the solution as function of the roots and not of the coefficients of the entire polynomial. Any reference / formula for that?

Thanks!

Comment: You can use Vieta’s formulae to compute the coefficients of $p$ as functions of its roots.

Comment: Thanks @Mindlack I knew the Vieta's formula but I was thinking that this integral can be iteratively solved by parts, which is quite tedious. I was looking for the final expression of integration by parts applied n times.